# How to keep context in foreach loop of ko virtual element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

I am wondering, why the variable 'Value.SpecificValue' could be used in one case and in the other not (see comments inline).

I am using the code as a template. My input is the object 'Value'.

It's properties are Value.SpeficValue (String) and Value.List (List of {Name, Value} objects) where the Value should match the Value.SpeficValue.

Why do I not have access to the Value.SpecificValue in the foreach loop?

```
    <label data-bind="text: Value.SpecificValue"></label> @*working*@
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: Value.List, as: 'list' } -->
    <div class="form-check">

        <label data-bind="text: Value.SpecificValue"></label> @*not working*@

        <label>
            <input type="radio" data-bind="value: list.Value, checked: Value.SelectedValue, attr:{id:ElementId}"> <span class="label-text" data-bind="text: list.Name"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout foreach binding has its own binding context. The $data is the current data item of the foreach loop.

To access `Value.SpecificValue` which is now on an outer context. You need to use $parent property of the binding context to make it work.

```
<label data-bind="text: $parent.Value.SpecificValue"></label>
```